# Rust binary stuck when started with valgrind

Tags: rust, valgrind

I am trying to perform some leak check for my binary that has been generated from a Rust project by doing `cargo build --release`

I am using valgrind for the purpose and here is my command

```
valgrind  --leak-check=full  --show-leak-kinds=all ./binary
```

However after this instruction, I get the following information on the shell

```
==1732828==    by 0x3553B4: binary::main (in /home/user/Desktop/binary)
==1732828==    by 0x31EF52: std::sys_common::backtrace::__rust_begin_short_backtrace (in /home/user/Desktop/binary)
==1732828==    by 0x289588: _ZN3std2rt10lang_start28_$u7b$$u7b$closure$u7d$$u7d$17hcb45a478cf2544afE.llvm.17780275718652616296 (in /home/user/Desktop/binary)
==1732828==  Address 0x0 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==1732828== 
==1732828== Warning: unimplemented fcntl command: 1036
```

The binary gets stuck after this warning `unimplemented fcntl command`.

When I run without valgrind, the operation of the project binary is normal.
Is it possible to deduce the reason for this behavior from the warnings presented?

Comment: I may be entirely off, but to my uneducated rust eye it looks like a nullref that shows up in a closure, but the reason is not very easy to pinpoint due to the release build's lack of debug info and the not entirely straight forward name mangling. Do you get the same error with a debug build, and do you get more info from Valgrind in that case?

Comment: Can you add more info (OS, CPU, Valgrind version)? Could you also add a small reproducer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell there are two problems. Possibly three.

1. An error in your code that you need to fix.
2. The fcntl 'HINTS' aren't supported by Valgrind https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/include/uapi/linux/fcntl.h
3. Valgrind ought to demangle rust symbols, so there may be a problem there.